# Listen for Browser Events in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, addeventlistener

Is there a way to attach event listeners to browser events in a Protractor test?

I know Protractor is running as a Node program, but I'm curious if anyone has done this with a Node package like [browserevent](https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserevent).

Looking for any examples if so.

Comment: Why do you need to wait for browser events? Protractor is supposed to do end to end testing, and your users most likely don't know when an event arrives, except for some visual indication which you should track.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion in the protractor spirit, No it's not possible . Protractor is a layer over selenium webdriver. Webdriver is a kind of JSON protocol that send command to communicate to the browser. Those command are store in a queue of promises and then come back async to Protractor. Then you could do Assertion with  the "Expect" keyword of jasmine to inspect the DOM.

If you still need to find a way, you try the hacker way :

browser.driver.executeScript("YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE;");

Then you Wrap this call in a browser.wait(), but I would not recommend such way.

Thank you

Comment: It should be `executeAsyncScript` then, but indeed that's a very bad idea

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question but I just want to add some information here, maybe it was not there when this question was asked. As it seems  in question and comments that it is for Javascript implementation of webdriver , which is [`webdriverjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverjs/v/1.7.3) . `Protractor` is a wrapper around `Webdriverjs` , so it should be valid here.

You should be able to use `addEventListener` command to add any browser supported [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Note, this is only supported in chrome currently

Also, this is an experimental feature in webdriver.js so  one has to add

```
var client = WebdriverJS.remote({
    logLevel: 'verbose',
    experimental: true, // <-- enables browser side eventhandling
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
});
```

And then register events like

```
client
    .url('http://google.com')
    .addEventListener('dblclick','#hplogo', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target); // -> 'id("hplogo")'
        console.log(e.type); // -> 'dblclick'
        console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY); // -> 239 524
    })
    .doubleClick('#hplogo') // triggers event
    .end();
```

You can use `removeEventListener` to unregister any registered listeners

Evenhandling in Node.js environment is also supported as implied by this

`WebdriverJS inherits several function from the NodeJS EventEmitter object`